# EffortException when trying to BulkInsert a class with a nullable enum

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-plus, effort

I'm trying to write some tests that assert my repository implementation is correct. I'm using Entity-Framework-Extensions library's `BulkInsert` method. The class I'm inserting has a nullable enum as a property. When I execute my test I get an EffortException that stems from a System.InvalidCastException. The message seems to indicate that the enum string value is being used *not* its corresponding int value. Is there some sort of annotation / config I can provide to get it to properly convert the enum.

> Effort.Exceptions.EffortException An unhandled exception occurred
> while trying to assign value 'StateTransition' to Property
> 'MandatoryJobCommentType' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'
> during entity initialization for table
> 'Effort.Internal.DbManagement.Schema.TableName'    at
> Effort.Internal.DbManagement.Schema.DbTableInfo.HandleConvertException(Exception
> exception, PropertyInfo property, Object value)

Comment: It is possible for you to show a runnable example of code that throw this error? At this moment, it hard to understand why the StateTransition enum is getting mapped to a nullable int. You can also report this error with a runnable project on the effort issue tracker: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Effort/issues

Comment: @JonathanMagnan sorry for the delay, but I've just added a minimal working example that reproduces the error I see in our project to your issue tracker. Hopefully that helps you / your team understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was inside the [Entity Framework Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/) library when a nullable `enum` was used with a bulk operations (only for Effort).

The issue has been fixed in the [v7.100.0.0](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/releases/tag/7.100.0.0)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Effort](https://entityframework-effort.net/) and  [Entity Framework Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Comment: Just to confirm @Jonathan Magnan's post, the v7.100.0.0 release resolves the issue  I'd encountered. If anyone else is having problems with Entity Framework Effort or Entity Framework Extensions it's definitely worth making a sample that reproduces your issue and reporting it on their bug tracker. They were very responsive and turned the fix round quickly.